# Initialize Redux state with data from websocket

Tags: reactjs, websocket, redux, react-redux

I'm building a React-Redux application where a property in the state object is populated by data from a websocket connection.

What's the  most efficient way to do this and keep my app in sync with data fetched from the websocket.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets keeps listening for any update, so a good place to initialize it would be in a componentDidMount from a component.
Next step, since you are using redux, you will want to dispatch an action that updates your application state.

For the part of handling websocket logic I suggest you use a library for this kind of purpose you don't want to reinvent the wheel here. Just by searching for the words 'websocket react' you will find multiple options.